# how to remove meta http-equiv tag in xsl

Tags: css, xml, xslt, fonts, font-awesome

I have used font awesome icon in my project. The html page generate from XSL templates. After searching lots of question. I decided to add a meta tag at in head as first ta. but xsl alwys put a auto generate meta tag as follows-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="IE=9; IE=EDGE" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css?ver=T1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=T1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?ver=T1.0" />
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

My requirement is displaying Custom font and Font Awesome icon on IE9 & IE11 compatibility view. Currently Not display as stated.

So I want to try with putting X-UA-Compatible meta tag first tag.So How can I do this ? or how to fix that font awesome and custom font work properly IE9 & IE11 compatibility view?

Here is my XSL -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
    <xsl:include href="portalheader.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:if test="//ajax">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//ajax/*"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(//ajax)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//wp"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wp">
        <html>
            <head>
                <xsl:if test="xua">
                     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9"/>
                </xsl:if>

                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <link href="css/picdef.css?ver=T1.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen"/>
                <link href="css/jquery-ui.css?ver=T1.0" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen" type="text/css"/>
                <link href="css/print.css?ver=T1.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print" />
                <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=T1.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
                <link href="css/style.css?ver=T1.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
                <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="//style">
                    <link href="{.}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:call-template name="includejava"/>
                <xsl:if test="not(popup)">
                <xsl:call-template name="portalheader" />
                </xsl:if>
            </head>


            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(frame)">
                  <xsl:call-template name="newpagetop"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="page|popup"/>
            </xsl:if>
.......................
..........................
..........................
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="includejava">
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?ver=T1.0" type="text/javascript"/>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js?ver=T1.0" type="text/javascript"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="pagemenu">
        <xsl:if test="menu">
            <div class="pagebar" style="width:50%">
                <div class="line">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mainmenu">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="menu"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <div class="content">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <option title="{@title}">
            <xsl:if test="@key">
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(@key)">
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </option>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="lable">
        <lable>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </lable>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="br">
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="space">
        <div style="height:5px;width:5px"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="action">
        <a>
            <xsl:if test="not(@href)">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="moveaction">
        <a class="empty">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <img alt="drag" src="images/c.gif" class="dragdrop move but" style="margin-right:4px"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="submit">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="{.}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </input>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="submit">
        <xsl:call-template name="submit"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="submitbar">
        <div class="submitbar">
            <xsl:call-template name="submit"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="wrap">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" style="overflow:hidden" title="{text()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="jscript">
        <div >
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>

        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="div">
          <div>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@space">
                <div style="height:5px;width:5px"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@java">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@java"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@href">
                <xsl:call-template name="link"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@javax">
        <a href="javascript:" java="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="../node()"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="iframe">
        <iframe frameBorder="0" width="100%"  id="{@id}" class="{@class}">
            <xsl:attribute name="addr">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </iframe>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@disabled">
        <xsl:attribute name="disabled">disabled</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xmlhtml">
    <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="copy">
    <xsl:for-each select="*"><xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>
    </xsl:copy></xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@mandatory">
        <xsl:attribute name="mandatory">1</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```